# Play sprite sheet on canvas slower than frame rate

Tags: javascript, typescript, game-engine

I have a sprite renderer which tells my game engine how to render a sprite. The update method in this class gets called about `120` times per second. Running through a sprite sheet at that speed is too fast.

In my sprite class I have a property called `duration`, which tells the renderer how many seconds the sprite should play for. Once it has reached the last frame it should start over.

I am not exactly sure how to calculate this with an `update` that runs `120` times a second, and a sprite sheet that should last for `x` seconds till it starts over.

```
class SpriteRenderer extends Component {

    // The current frame
    public frame: number = 0;
    // The sprite reference
    public sprite: Sprite = null;

    update() {

        // Number of frames in the sprite sheet
        let frames = this.sprite.frames;
        if (frames > 0) {
            // The time in seconds the sprite sheet should play
            let duration = this.sprite.duration;

            if (/* What should go here? */) {
                this.frame++;
                if (this.frame > frames - 1) {
                    this.frame = 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a time variable that controls the frame time.
This variable is a float and once it gets large enough you can do the next frame and reset the variable.

I have never done any type script, but this may work. It will at least give you an idea of what i am talking about.

If the update runs 120 times every second that means that it runs every 60/120 seconds 0.5.

Now we can increment `currentTime` by 0.5 and check if the `currentTime` > `sprite.duration`*60 I think. :)

Exampe:

```
class SpriteRenderer extends Component {

    // The current frame
    public frame: number = 0;
    // The sprite reference
    public sprite: Sprite = null;
    public currentTime: number = 0.0; //This is the current time.
    public updateTime: number = this.sprite.duration*60; //This is how long the update time is.
    update() {
        this.currentTime += 0.5; //Add to the current time.
        // Number of frames in the sprite sheet
        let frames = this.sprite.frames;
        if (frames > 0) {
            // The time in seconds the sprite sheet should play
            let duration = this.sprite.duration;

            if (this.currentTime > this.sprite.duration*60) { //Check if the current time is more than the wait time.
                this.currentTime = 0.0; //Reset the wait time.
                this.frame++;
                if (this.frame > frames - 1) {
                    this.frame = 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Pretty close, `this.currentTime += 0.01;` in my case should be `this.currentTime += Time.deltaTime;` `this.udateTime` would be `duration`. Setting my duration to `1`, it plays 1 frame a second, which is closer than it was.

Comment: Yeah I was going to update my answer to calculate the time that should add per second and how long it will take.

Comment: Closer! My if now looks like this `if (this.currentTime > duration * Time.deltaTime)` my `deltaTime` is about `0.008`. It is still a little fast. If I set duration to 5 it is about 1 second...

Comment: Should I update my code to fit the time calculations I did?

Comment: Sure. Could you also use `Time.deltaTime` (The time between frames)

Comment: So deltaTime accounts for lag?

Comment: Alright! Here is what I have: `private currentTime`, I don't need the `updateTime`. I update currentTime: `this.currentTime += Time.deltaTime * 0.1;`, then check it like this: `if (this.currentTime > duration * Time.deltaTime)`. It seems to work!

Comment: I used a modified version of your answer.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)